# Como pegar dados com sharedpreferences?

Tags: android

Na minha tela de login eu estou usando um checkbox para que o usuario escolha se ira querer mantes conectado ou não. Eu gostaria de saber como consigo pegar os dados do usuario depois de ja entrar no app.Obrigado

Comment: Me desculpe, mas você sequer procurou ou tentou implementar antes de vir aqui perguntar?

Comment: Tentei irmão, conseguir achar nao, mas acabei de resolver com o link do acklay. Obrigado